# Connect HSQLDB Server

Tags: spring-boot, server, client, database-connection, hsqldb

I would like to connect my hsqldb by an client like squirrel. Before I used hsqldb in memory, to have that feature to connect with another client, I want to use the server now. But I am stucking connecting it.

What I have so far:

I start the hsqldb as Spring-Boot-Application:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ApplicationInfra {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(ApplicationInfra.class, args);

        final HyperSqlDbServer dbServer = context.getBean(HyperSqlDbServer.class);
        dbServer.displayInfo();

        try (final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            do {
                System.out.println("Shutdown HSQLDB?[Y/N]: ");
            } while (sc.hasNext() && (!sc.next().equalsIgnoreCase("y")));
        }

        // =============================================================

        // SHUTDOWN DATABASE ...
        final DataSource dataSource = context.getBean(DataSource.class);
        final JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        template.execute("SHUTDOWN");

        context.close();
    }
}
```

My HyperSqlDbServer class:

```
@Configuration
public class HyperSqlDbServer implements SmartLifecycle {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HyperSqlDbServer.class);
    private HsqlProperties properties;
    private Server server;
    private boolean running = false;

    public HyperSqlDbServer() {
        final Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("server.database.0", "file:./hsqldb/bbsng");
        props.setProperty("server.dbname.0", "bbsng");
        props.setProperty("server.remote_open", "true");
        props.setProperty("server.trace", "true");
        props.setProperty("hsqldb.reconfig_logging", "false");
        properties = new HsqlProperties(props);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRunning() {
        if (server != null)
            server.checkRunning(running);
        return running;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        if (server == null) {
            logger.info("Starting HSQL server...");
            server = new Server();
            try {
                server.setProperties(properties);
                server.start();
                running = true;
            } catch (AclFormatException afe) {
                logger.error("Error starting HSQL server.", afe);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("Error starting HSQL server.", e);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        logger.info("Stopping HSQL server...");
        if (server != null) {
            server.stop();
            running = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getPhase() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAutoStartup() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(Runnable runnable) {
        stop();
        runnable.run();
    }

}
```

My Application properties

```
# DATA-SOURCE CONFIGURATION:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc\:hsqldb\:bbsng
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

The console says that hibernate creates the new tables:

```
Hibernate: create table apprentice (id bigint not null, city varchar(255), street varchar(255), street_number varchar(255), urban_district varchar(255), zip varchar(255), email varchar(255), fax varchar(255), mobile varchar(255), phone varchar(255), first_name varchar(255) not null, last_name varchar(255) not null, version integer, rural_district bigint, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table company (id bigint not null, city varchar(255), street varchar(255), street_number varchar(255), urban_district varchar(255), zip varchar(255), email varchar(255), fax varchar(255), mobile varchar(255), phone varchar(255), name varchar(255) not null, number varchar(255) not null, version integer, rural_district bigint, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table company_occupation_combination (id bigint not null, version integer, company bigint not null, occupation_combination bigint not null, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table contract (id bigint not null, education_end date not null, education_start date not null, status integer not null, version integer, apprentice bigint not null, company_occupation_combination bigint not null, office bigint not null, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table district (id bigint not null, name varchar(255) not null, version integer, primary key (id))

...
```

And HSQLDB Server started:

```
2015-12-28 21:20:24.765  INFO 9832 --- [           main] at.compax.bbsng.infra.HyperSqlDbServer   : Starting HSQL server...
[Server@35c9a231]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) entered
[Server@35c9a231]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) exited
[Server@35c9a231]: Initiating startup sequence...
[Server@35c9a231]: Server socket opened successfully in 0 ms.
[Server@35c9a231]: Database [index=0, id=1, db=file:./hsqldb/bbsng, alias=bbsng] opened sucessfully in 40 ms.
[Server@35c9a231]: Startup sequence completed in 50 ms.
[Server@35c9a231]: 2015-12-28 21:20:24.815 HSQLDB server 2.3.3 is online on port 9001
[Server@35c9a231]: To close normally, connect and execute SHUTDOWN SQL
[Server@35c9a231]: From command line, use [Ctrl]+[C] to abort abruptly
```

**But I cant find the table with squirrel!**
My configuration looks like:

[image: Squirrel HSQLDB Configuration]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to write your issue to stackoverflow and you will see your own mistake.

My Datasource was not correct and hibernate added the tables in another created database. The solution is to fix in application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc\:hsqldb\:file\:./hsqldb/bbsng
```